# Can anyone tell me why the split in the for loop just works for the last line of the file?

Tags: python, split

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    new=line.split()
for word in new:
    if word in lst:
        continue
    lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: those loops are supposed to be nested, not sequential. put the second loop in the first one or you will only work on the last line of the file...

Comment: Your second for loop needs to be inside your first for loop

Comment: I tried, but it said bad input in my line 6 and idk why

Comment: @ChâuTrinh, you might be mixing tabs and spaces in your editor. Please indent your code properly, and your code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops need to be nested.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    new=line.split()
    for word in new:
        if word in lst:
            continue
        lst.append(word)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: thank u, it works <3 but the loop doesnt include the print (lst)

Comment: I hope the answer helps. If it does, please tick it :)